# Validar procedimiento Almacenado

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedure

Hola chicos tengo una pregunta, he intenado de muchas maneras pero no he podido

he creado un pequeño proyecto con procedimientos almacenados pero no se como puedo enviar un mensaje si el registro ya existe

este es mi codificacion en c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Datos;
using Entidad;

namespace Presentacion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void limpiar()
        {
            TxtDescripcion.Text = null;
            TxtNombre.Text = null;
            TxtPrecio.Text = null;

            TxtNombre.Focus();
        }

        Tabla1E tE = new Tabla1E();
        Tabla1D tD = new Tabla1D();

        string idLaTabla;
        string operacion = "insertar";

        private void BtnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var hasNumber = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");

            if (TxtDescripcion.Text == "" && TxtNombre.Text == "" && TxtPrecio.Text =="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor rellene los campos");
                TxtNombre.Focus();
            }
            else if (TxtNombre.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Digite el Nombre");
                TxtNombre.Focus();
            }
            else if (TxtDescripcion.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Digite la descripción");
                TxtDescripcion.Focus();
            }
            else if(TxtPrecio.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Digite el Precio");
                TxtPrecio.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!hasNumber.IsMatch(TxtPrecio.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La Contraseña debe contener solo numeros");
                    TxtPrecio.Focus();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    tE.NombreTabla1 = TxtNombre.Text.Trim();
                    tE.Descripcion = TxtDescripcion.Text.Trim();
                    tE.PrecioProducto = Convert.ToDouble(TxtPrecio.Text.Trim());
                    tD.agregarTabla1(tE);
                    MessageBox.Show("Agregado");
                    limpiar();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

y esta es mi codificacion en SQL Server

```
create database Store_Procedure_Test
go
use Store_Procedure_Test
go
---  TABLAS  ---    
create table Tabla1
(
IDTabla1 int identity (1,1) primary key,
NombreTabla1 varchar(30),
Descripcion varchar(250),
PrecioProducto float    
)
go
insert into Tabla1 values('Hola','Mundo',15)
go
--------------

------------------------------------------
---  Procedimientos Almacenados  ---    


-- agregar datos a las tablas
create procedure sp_agregarTabla1
@NombreTabla1 varchar(30),
@Descripcion varchar(250),
@PrecioProducto float       
as

if exists(select * from Tabla1 where NombreTabla1=@NombreTabla1)
begin
print('ya existe'+@NombreTabla1)
return
end

begin
insert into Tabla1 (NombreTabla1,Descripcion,PrecioProducto) values (@NombreTabla1,@Descripcion,@PrecioProducto)
end
--
```

lo que necesito su apoyo es como mostrar un mensaje si el registro ya existe

Ya he realizado el proceso y si el registro esta duplicado no lo guarda pero no me arroja ninguna alerta ni nada por el estilo, simplemente dice guardado pero la validacion del procedimiento almacenado evita que se guarde

lo que quiero es que arroje un mensaje que diga que ya existe

Answer (score 3):

Podrías lanzar una excepción particular en tu procedimiento t-sql. Algo que tu aplicación pueda escuchar y saber que no recorrió el camino feliz.

```
-- agregar datos a las tablas
create procedure sp_agregarTabla1
@NombreTabla1 varchar(30),
@Descripcion varchar(250),
@PrecioProducto float       
as

if exists(select * from Tabla1 where NombreTabla1=@NombreTabla1)
begin
   print('ya existe'+@NombreTabla1)
   THROW 51001, 'El registro ya existe.', 1;  
end
```

Tu aplicación va a ver un mensaje

```
Msg 51001, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
 
El registro ya existe.
```

Que debes atrapar y controlar como desees.

Answer (score 3):

Tambien podrias hacer que el Procedure te regrese un mensaje agregando una variable output

```
create procedure sp_agregarTabla1
@NombreTabla1 varchar(30),
@Descripcion varchar(250),
@PrecioProducto float,
@Mensaje Varchar(255) Output

if exists(select * from Tabla1 where NombreTabla1=@NombreTabla1)
begin
   Set @Mensaje = 'ya existe'+@NombreTabla1
end
```